# Google BigQuery sum(case when... to exclude groups if the column contains a value not from the list

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The the code is correct, but at the end you see `SUM(CASE WHEN token_address NOT IN (...`
What i am trying to do here is to exclude groups (transaction_hash) if any of the values from `token_address` is not from the list `'0x6c3f90f043a72fa612cbac8115ee7e52bde6e490','0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f','0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48','0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7'`.

I run this code, and I still see transaction_hash groups when token_address that is not one of the four (see the screenshot below). How can i modify the code so that token_address in my final query table ONLY includes these 4 tokens above.

```
WITH temp AS (
   SELECT transaction_hash, 
       block_timestamp, 
       from_address, 
       to_address, 
       CASE
         WHEN token_address = '0x6c3f90f043a72fa612cbac8115ee7e52bde6e490' THEN CAST(value AS FLOAT64) / POW(10, 18)
         WHEN token_address = '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f' THEN CAST(value AS FLOAT64) / POW(10, 18)
         WHEN token_address = '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48' THEN CAST(value AS FLOAT64) / POW(10, 6)
         WHEN token_address = '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7' THEN CAST(value AS FLOAT64) / POW(10, 6)
         ELSE CAST(value AS FLOAT64) / POW(10, 18)
       END AS value,
       CASE 
         WHEN token_address = '0x6c3f90f043a72fa612cbac8115ee7e52bde6e490' THEN '3pool LP'
         WHEN token_address = '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f' THEN 'DAI'
         WHEN token_address = '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48' THEN 'USDC'
         WHEN token_address = '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7' THEN 'USDT'
         ELSE token_address
       END AS token_address,
       data
  FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.curvepools.traces_transfers_allrouters` as t
  WHERE transaction_hash IN (
    SELECT transaction_hash
    FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.curvepools.traces_transfers_allrouters` as t
    WHERE (from_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7' OR to_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7')  # associated with 3pool
    AND token_address IN ('0x6c3f90f043a72fa612cbac8115ee7e52bde6e490', # 3pool LP
                          '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f', # DAI
                          '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48', # USDC
                          '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7') # USDT      
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.curvepools.traces_transfers_allrouters` as t2
      WHERE t2.transaction_hash = t.transaction_hash
        AND (t2.from_address = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' OR t2.to_address = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.curvepools.traces_transfers_allrouters` as t3
      WHERE t3.transaction_hash = t.transaction_hash
        AND (t3.token_address = 'ETH' AND CAST(t3.value AS FLOAT64) > 0)
    )
    GROUP BY transaction_hash
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1 AND SUM(CASE WHEN token_address NOT IN (
        '0x6c3f90f043a72fa612cbac8115ee7e52bde6e490', # 3pool LP
        '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f', # DAI
        '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48', # USDC
        '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7'  # USDT      
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 
)

ORDER BY transaction_hash, data
)
SELECT * FROM temp
WHERE from_address NOT IN (SELECT address FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.results.contracts`) OR to_address NOT IN (SELECT address FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.results.contracts`)
ORDER BY transaction_hash, data
```

[image]

Comment: Please structure your code better, e.g. use more CTE tables. The first `WHERE transaction_hash IN (` is the filter of your data. Then you query the `transaction_hash` again and filter on two conditions: `WHERE (from_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7' OR to_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7')  # associated with 3pool` The final filter on the `token_address` is only consider the part where the addresses are set to the above.

Comment: i only started SQL 2 weeks ago. could you be kind to modify the code so I get desired output? thankfully i am using chatgpt but there is a limit in how much i can do with it and it's taking so long :( i have been struggling with this for hrs. it'd be tremendously helpful.

Comment: How do you want to filter?
A) If for a `transaction_hash` a `token_address` is different from the 4 given, shall the whole `transaction_hash` be removed? Or  B)  only keep the 4 right `token_address`?

Comment: the whole transaction_hash should be removed!

Comment: Well, it is not clear what your code shall do. SQL is a scripting language what does not describe what you want to do. By looking on a SQL code you cannot tell the goal of the writer. You can only correct it, if you know what the output shall be. All the filter are not clear why you set them this way and what you wanted to archive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is more a suggestion; I cannot run the query; thus there may some typos. You can edit this answer, to fix errors!

```sql
WITH helper as
#provide all information as a table
(Select  '0x6c3f90f043a72fa612cbac8115ee7e52bde6e490' token_address, 1/ POW(10, 18) scaling, '3pool LP' name
union all select '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f',  1/POW(10, 18), 'DAI'
union all select '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48', 1/ POW(10, 6), 'USDC'
union all select '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7',  1/ POW(10, 6), 'USDT'

 ),
 raw_data as ( # read in data from table
 Select * from `mindful-quasar-376118.curvepools.traces_transfers_allrouters`),
 
 filter1 as ( # 1st filter to include
 SELECT transaction_hash
 from raw_data
  left join helper
 where name is null and  
 (from_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7' OR to_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7')  # associated with 3pool
  ),
 
 filter_out as (#filter to exclude
  SELECT transaction_hash
 from raw_data
 where (t2.from_address = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' OR t2.to_address = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
 ),
 
  filter_out2 as (
  SELECT transaction_hash
 from raw_data
 left join helper
 where name is null
 or (t3.token_address = 'ETH' AND CAST(t3.value AS FLOAT64) > 0)
 ),
 
 data_filtered as (
 select * from 
 raw_data as t
  WHERE 
 # please comment the next two lines out, if you want to included only these addresses
  #(from_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7' OR to_address = '0xbebc44782c7db0a1a60cb6fe97d0b483032ff1c7')  # associated with 3pool
  #  and

  transaction_hash IN (
  select * from
(
    SELECT transaction_hash
    FROM filter1    # keep these 
   except distinct   # but remove:
   (
      SELECT *
      FROM filter_out # filter
      union all
      SELECT *
      FROM filter_out2 #filter
    )
    )
    GROUP BY transaction_hash
   # HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1 # you do not need this?
)
 ),

temp AS (
   SELECT transaction_hash, 
       block_timestamp, 
       from_address, 
       to_address, 
       CAST(value AS FLOAT64) * ifnull(scaling,1/ POW(10, 18))  AS value,
    ifnull(name, token_address ) as token_address,

       data
  FROM data_filtered

left join helper

ORDER BY transaction_hash, data
)
SELECT * FROM temp
WHERE from_address NOT IN (SELECT address FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.results.contracts`) OR to_address NOT IN (SELECT address FROM `mindful-quasar-376118.results.contracts`)
ORDER BY transaction_hash, data
```

Comment: there are simply too many changes,,,  it's beyond my understanding at this point.. but thanks a lot for trying to help tho.